# Centralizing Multiple VPN Connections to Avoid Client Conflicts on Employee Laptops

Tags: networking, vpn

I work for a company that delivers support to multiple healthcare institutions. Each of these institutions requires us to connect via their specific VPN software using individual accounts provided to us.

**Issue**

Our employees currently have 4 or more VPN clients installed on their laptops. This often leads to conflicts between the VPN clients and can sometimes disrupt regular internet traffic.

**Objective**

I'm looking for a solution where our employees can connect to a centralized company server, which would handle the various VPN connections. This would ideally allow employees to avoid installing multiple VPN clients on their laptops. Instead, they would connect to our server, which in turn would manage and "share" the specific VPN connection needed.

**Given-When-Then**

**Given** an employee with a single connection to a central company server,

**When** they need to access resources from a specific healthcare institution,

**Then** the central server should establish the appropriate VPN connection to that institution, allowing the employee to access the resources without directly managing multiple VPN clients on their laptop.

*Does anyone have experience or suggestions for achieving this setup?*

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to research this topic within my company but nobody knew the answer. I also did some research online before posting this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a VPN appliance, like a F5 BigIp or a Check Point appliance or Palo Alto(expensive).

You can then also create a site site vpn between your network and the network of the institution. In the corporate world vpns are not connected between servers but between networks.

Comment: Remember that the primary use case is to provide support to our customers which demand connecting to their VPN with their specific provided software. So it’s use case is on demand, for short periods at a time

Comment: Then you can't standardize it too one solution if they demand that, or you have to turn on the demand ask them to help for setting up a site to site. Because you don't have access to the source code of those vpn clients, so you don't know which encryption algorithms your vpn solution has to support

Comment: I have found one possible solution, but have not the expertise to conclude if this is what i am looking for. However this does raise my hopes:

https://gist.github.com/Koubek/b89d40d80dffd86d903a0725a6324900